# Cannot build Advanced Installer because icon is missing

Tags: build, icons, installation

I have a problem with Advanced Installer - cannot build a project! I have a message "Resources referred by the project are missing. ControlCenter\ControlCenter\Icons\system.ico but I cannot find where the configuration it. When I make a search for system.ico in the project I really find the configuration of "Icon - SourcePath=\ccl\Icons\system.ico but if I click on "go to definition" it does nothing! How can I find the configuration?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found the way to fix it was to edit the setup project in notepad and fix the path issue there. Low-and-behold it worked!.

Answer (score 0):

There a few places a icon can be found, those are:

- Product Details page
- Media page
- Themes page
- Updater page
- Java Products page

These are the most used pages, there are still other places were icons can be found.
You can also look in Table Editor page, in **Binary** table to change the source of your icon.

If you still have problems finding it just mail the project file to the support team.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I found it in Table Editor! But! How can I make changes to it? If I am trying to delete the raw it just marks with a green line but it does not any changes so I still cannot build the project! How can I delete the raw?

Comment: The same result if I am trying to edit the raw - still the same error and I cannot build the project :(

Comment: Searching for the name visible in the Name column from Binary table should help you find the view were the icon is used. If you still cannot find it send us the project and we will delete it for you.

Comment: I cannot find the place where the icon used are. How can I send you my file?

Comment: send a mail with it at support at advancedinstaller dot com